# Pass function as parameter C# (Timer.Enable)

Tags: c#, timer

i'm learning c# and i'm trying some stuff with the System.Timers.Timer, and i'm having a problem, cause i want to make a function that receives another function so i could 'bind' it to the timer.Elapsed event. I'm trying to build something like:

```
 public void timerElapsedMethod(my method)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += my method;
    }
```

There is a way where i can do that ?

edit 1:

Guys, what i'm trying to do is, baiscally encapsulate the timer class, so i want a user to call my function passing his function as an argument.

Like:

```
 class MyTimer
{
    public static Timer timer;

    public MyTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    internal void *timerElapsedMeth*(Action<object, ElapsedEventArgs> method)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (if i put method here i get an error);
    }

}
```

Now imagine someone wants to use my class and wanna do something like:

```
 class SomeUserRandomClass
{
    public static MyTimer mytimer;

    public SomeUserRandomClass()
    {
        mytimer = new MyTimer();
    }

    public void userRandomMethod()
    {
       some code...
    }

  myTimer.*timerElapsedMeth*(userRandomMethod);

}
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Thx

Comment: You should be able to set your method signature as `public void timerElapsedMethod(Action<object, ElapsedEventArgs> myMethod)` and then call it like `timerElapsedMethod(someMethodThatAcceptsAnObjectAndElapsedEventArgs)`

Comment: thx for your response. And if i want to call a function who is in another class ? I'll edit my post to clarify this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like the following.

I wouldn't try to try and asign it to the event directly. But hide the event details

```
class MyTimer
{
    private readonly Action _userAction;
    private Timer timer;

    public MyTimer(Action userAction)
    {
        _userAction = userAction;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _userAction?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Keith, you solution worked for me. Thank you so much. However, if i want to pass a function who takes arguments herself ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using lambda expressions.

```
public void timerElapsedMethod(Action myMethod) {
        var timer =new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
            myMethod?.Invoke();
        };
    }
```

if myMethod needs parameters, you can edit the timerElapsedMethod to take parameters.

```
public void timerElapsedMethod(Action myMethod, int param) {
        var timer =new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
            myMethod?.Invoke(param);
        };
    }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: That second example should use a `Action<int>`.

Comment: Yeah sure. That's another way to do it

Comment: It's not another way, it's the only way that will actually compile because the `Action` delegate and thus it's `Invoke` does not take any parameters.

Comment: Hey guys, i'm trying your solution but it doesn't work, or i'm missing something. I get this compilation error:
** "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'**

Comment: The method you will pass as an argument must return void and be parameterless. It must have this signature: void <methodName>(){}.

Comment: For the second method. you will need to pass a method that returns void but takes a single int parameter. This is because the signature of Action<int> is void <methodName>(int param){}.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in your wrapper class which is fired when the timer event is fired.

```
class MyTimer
{
    // Is there a reason you want this timer to be public? Otherwise make it private.
    public static Timer timer;

    public event EventHandler<ElapsedEventArgs> OnTimerEvent;

    public MyTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnTimerEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Using your timer class:

```
class SomeUserRandomClass
{
    private static MyTimer mytimer;

    public SomeUserRandomClass()
    {
        mytimer = new MyTimer();
        myTimer += TimerEventHandler;   // Register to the event
    }

    public void userRandomMethod()
    {
       some code...
    }

    private static void TimerEventHandler(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
}
```

Make sure to "unregister" the event when you Dispose your `SomeUserRandomClass`:

```
myTimer -= TimerEventHandler;
```

Comment: The OnTimedEvent cannot be static as it needs to reference the class variables